# Insert in Oracle Data Acces with C#

Tags: c#, oracle

Im trying to insert in a oracle table with this code, and thows this error message: "The value is not within the expected range."

I have tried different ways but always throws the same error.

```
oc.Open();

OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter();



OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ROW_ID, CREATED, STATUS) " +
   "VALUES (:pROW_ID, :pCREATED, :pSTATUS", oc);


OracleParameter ROW_ID = new OracleParameter("pROW_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 15, "ROW_ID");
OracleParameter CREATED = new OracleParameter("pCREATED", OracleDbType.Date, 30, "CREATED");
OracleParameter STATUS = new OracleParameter("pASIGNADO", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 15, "STATUS");
ROW_ID.Value = BDOracleObtenerRowIDBackOffice();

ROW_ID.Value = = "146721030020001";
CREATED.Value = "SYSDATE";
STATUS.Value = "ON_HOLD";

cmd.Parameters.Add("pROW_ID", ROW_ID);  //<-- Here throws exception
cmd.Parameters.Add("pCREATED", CREATED);
cmd.Parameters.Add("pSTATUS", STATUS);

oda.InsertCommand = cmd;
```

> Trace:
>      at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter..ctor(String parameterName, Object obj)
>      at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection.Add(String name, Object val)
>      at TestCore.MyClass.functionInsert(String param) at C:\Users\user_01\source\repos\file.cs:línea 2945

Comment: The parameters need a '@'.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @jdweng - this is ODP...not microsoft's deprecated oracle classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have something similar in the application I'm working on. This should be enough of an overview, but you might want to change the parameter names and values from what I have to suit your needs when you add the Oracle Parameter to `cmd`.

```
using(var conn = new OracleConnection("CONNECTIONSTRING")
{
   conn.Open();

   var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ROW_ID, CREATED, STATUS) VALUES (:pROW_ID, :pCREATED, :pSTATUS");

   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(":pROW_ID", OracleDbType.whateverType, "146721030020001", ParameterDirection.Input);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(":pCREATED", OracleDbType.whateverType, "SYSDATE", ParameterDirection.Input);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(":pASIGNADO", OracleDbType.whateverType, "ON_HOLD", ParameterDirection.Input);

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
}
```

Note: If ROW_ID is a PK and has a sequence to auto generate the value, you'll want to use the sequence associated with it instead of passing a parameter:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ROW_ID, CREATED, STATUS) VALUES (NAME_OF_SEQUENCE.nextval, :pCREATED, :pSTATUS");
```

Another note: if you want to do bulk inserts instead of just single rows, I'd highly suggest using Array Binding: http://burnignorance.com/database-tips-and-tricks/bulk-copy-with-oracle-using-array-binding/ the performance is quite outstanding with larger sets of data.

In regards to `"The value is not within the expected range."` double check the value against the column in the database to ensure it is valid, and then use the correct `OracleDbType` that corresponds with it.